Firebase functions emulator get actor user information
I need to construct specific linked documents when Firestore object is created, and I need to know who created the specific document. Based on documentation I should be able to use onDocumentCreatedWithAuthContext that should contain auth information.
I have not yet deployed this to Firebase, only using the latest firebase emulator locally. This is my function, and I do not get the proper auth information.
"use strict";

// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {onDocumentCreatedWithAuthContext} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

exports.createFamilyLinks = onDocumentCreatedWithAuthContext("/thecollection/{documentId}", (event) => {
  const { authType, authId } = event;
  logger.log(authType, authId);
});

When document is created the log outputs:
{"severity":"INFO","message":"unknown fake-auth-id@gmail.com"}

Might this be a limitation with the Firebase emulator, or should I expect this to not be working? Reference documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#auth-context

Reported bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/7609

I have not been successful in getting this to work using emulators only either. I also get authType unknown and that same email as authId although I would expect the uid.
So, unfortunately I cannot help you with that and I am also looking for answers to this, however I can tell you this works for me in production, so to answer your question:

Might this be a limitation with the Firebase emulator, or should I
expect this to not be working?

It's working for me in production, but I get the same result as you locally.

Thanks for confirming the problem. I’ll report a bug about it.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/7609
